# How do I see if the passenger gem is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Not sure why this might be happening? I'm trying to get a ruby app I use working through Apache on port 80, but am stumbling at every hurdle :)

```
root../public/htdocs# bundle show passenger
Could not find gem 'passenger'.
Did you mean passenger?
root../public/htdocs# gem install passenger
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed passenger-5.0.21
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for passenger-5.0.21...
Installing RDoc documentation for passenger-5.0.21...
root../public/htdocs# bundle show passenger
Could not find gem 'passenger'.
Did you mean passenger?
```

Comment: `bundle install passenger` - not `gem`. There's a difference between the two - `bundle` is a local scope to a project whereas `gem` is system-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided no bakcground info about the OS you are running , the package manager you using to manage different versions of Ruby ,  gems  `e.g "rbenv ,  rvm ....etc"` how you are managing your gems .. `e.g  locally , globally , via gemset... etc` . So , generally speaking you can either , run `gem list` and grep for the name of the gem like below with the gem qualifier as an example :

```
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/shop_app/depot2$ gem list | grep uglif*
uglifier (2.7.2, 2.6.0, 2.5.3, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.0, 1.2.7, 1.2.4)
```

Or you can specify by passing the name of the gem as an ARG to `gem list`

```
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/shop_app/depot2$ gem list uglifier

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

uglifier (2.7.2, 2.6.0, 2.5.3, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.0, 1.2.7, 1.2.4)
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/shop_app/depot2$
```

Comment: That's fair enough, I don't know much about Ruby and I was hoping the issue was generic enough, not to require all that. I'm on a debian based OS on a VM. I'm not sure I'm using a package manager, but I think I'm managing them locally as the Gemfile came ready made with the app from Git. Neither of those two show commands show passenger though, given that it says `Successfully installed passenger-5.0.21` where has it gone (or how can I install it with my app)? @NullSoulException

Comment: I think because you are not using any ruby environment manager ..i.e RVM . The issue is that you ended up with two versions of Ruby ,  one is used in command line (e.g. to install gems) and the second is used to run rails server. That is why the one running the server can not see the gem...........RVM is easy to install and work with ... read more https://rvm.io/rvm/basics